# How do I add user data to url in Django?

Tags: python, django

I've got a function based view in Django called `userView`

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def userView(request):
    user = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        user_id = user.pk


    return render(request, "user_view.html", {'user': user})
```

and here's my URL for it

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^user/', userView, name='user'),
]
```

After my user has logged in, I'd like him to see his pk number in the URL. I.e., if the user's PK is `3` and the user directs their browser to `www.myapp.com/user`, the URL in the address bar should change to `www.myapp.com/user/3/`. How do I make that happen? I'm aware I need to edit the RegEx for the URL into

```
url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', userView, name='user')
```

but how do I pass the PK number to the URL?

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking. That URL already requires a user_id, so you can't get to that view without having it in the first place.

Comment: I edited the post to make it clearer. How do I pass the pk number to the url from the view

Comment: I still don't really understand. You're presumably redirecting from login to this view, why can't you put the number into that redirect URL?

Comment: So when the user directs their browser to `www.myapp.com/user/` you want the URL to change to `www.myapp.com/user/3/` (if the user's PK is 3)?

Comment: @das-g, yes that's exactly right.

Comment: I've edited your question to make that intend more clear. [Kostas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037021/how-do-i-add-user-data-to-url-in-django/39037675#39037675) should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Django expert but my guess is you want to redirect the user to his 'home page' after he is logged in. That can be done using the [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) method

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def userLoginView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect("/user/{0}".format(request.user.pk), user=request.user)
```

And then define a second view that will render the home page

```
def userView(request, user_id=None, user=None):
    return render(request, "user_view.html", {'user': user})
```

Also your url patterns should be as follows

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^user/', userLoginView, name='userlogin'),
     url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', userView, name='user')
]
```

Comment: Even better to use Django's reverse lookup. With your urlpatterns it would look something like: `return redirect(reverse('user', kwargs={'user_id': request.user.pk}))`. That way, if you would ever change your urlconf from `user/<id>` to, say, `profile/<id>`, all your redirects still work. See here for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse